# how can i resolve the issue in displaying the ajax search results in django?

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax, django-views

**Problem**
*The results are being retrieved by the ajax search function but when I display the data retrieved in the selector using `$(selector).htm(data)` it loads whole the page with a page with correct search results.*
*The code is attached below with the screenshot of what I'm getting from this code for a better understanding.*

**JS**

```
$('#searchsubmit').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        q = $('#search').val();
        console.log(q);
        updateContentBySearch(q);
  });
function updateContentBySearch(q) {
    var data = {};
    data['search_by'] = q
    // data["csrfmiddlewaretoken"] = $('#searchform [name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "{% url 'main:Search' %}",
        data: {
          'search_by': q,
          'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
          searchSuccess(data)
        }
      });

    }
    function searchSuccess(data, textStatus,jqXHR)
    {
      $('#search-results').html(data);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="row justify-content-center" style="text-align:center">
    <form class="d-flex col-md-6" id="searchform" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
     <div class="input-group mb-3" style="text-align:center">
    <input name="q" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="search">
    <button class="btn btn-primary shadow px-5 py-2" type="submit" id="searchsubmit">Search</button>
     </div>
  </form>
  </div>
  <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc; background: transparent;">
  <div class="row"  id="search-results">
  {% regroup transaction by productID as ProductList %}
  {% for productID in ProductList %}
 ///some code 

</div>
  {% endfor %}

</div>
```

**VIEWS**

```
@csrf_exempt
def search(request):
    q = request.POST.get('search_by')
    print(q)
    product = Products.objects.all()
    cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    transaction = transactions.objects.filter(productID__name__icontains=q,status='Enable').order_by('productID')
    print(transaction)
    context={
        'products':product,
        'transaction': transaction,
        'cart_product_form':cart_product_form
    }
    html = render_to_string('main/home.html',context)

    return JsonResponse(html,safe=False , content_type="application/json")
```

**SCREENSHOT**

[image]

*Now in this screenshot u can see it showing me two banners and search bars and after the second the products from the search results are displayed. It's like it loads the whole page again within the page from the selector i have passed data too.*

**DOES ANYONE KNOWS HOW TO RESOLE THIS ISSUE OR WHERE I HAVE DONE WRONG.**

Answer (score 0):

because you render `'main/home.html'` agin ! you just need send a json response with your `context` data and add it to web page with JS or create a new html template and render that with your context data and send that as response!

Comment: I don't want to the page to direct to another page or reload the page